# Using a For Loop to find a sequences expression [1/1+1/2+1/3...1/1000]

Tags: python, for-loop, math, sequence

I am needing assistance for an assignment. I am needing to use python to figure out how to create a "for Loop" that will do the following:

```
Series 1/1+1/2+1/3+1/4+...+1/1000 (which is expressed as 1000. ∑ n=1. 1 n ≈. 7.49)
```

I am needing the program to loop through all of them, printing each number out.
Example:

```
998 7.483469855949342

999 7.48447086055343

1000 7.485470860550343
```

The basic what I currently got is

```
for x in range(1, 1000):
```

I don't know why but I just struggling to get this equation to work in my head. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going in the right direction. Before the `for` loop you would require a sum variable, where you would store the value of the summation of `1/x`.

You can do that in a similar way:

```
sum = 0
for x in range(1, 1001):
    sum += (1/x)
    print(sum, x)
```

Here, I have initialized the sum variable to 0. After that, I iterate x over the values of [1, 1000] (both included). I find `1/x` and add it to the sum. Next, I print the values, as you wanted.

**NOTE:** `range(x, y)` method gives you a range from `x` to `y-1`

Comment: Bravo! The only issue I see here is that your are storing values into memory. This means slowness if dealing with big data. ;)

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel, you are right, however this seems to be beginner's question. We should not impose the effects of sluggishness of storing variables in memory right now (at this level), I guess.

Comment: Agree. I think for tutorials purposes, it is okay but were it to be a production code, efficiency is to be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

itertools are your best friend. The proposed answers is correct but would be slow for big data. If I were you I would do:

```
import itertools

a = map(lambda x:1/x,range(1,1001))

#print(list(itertools.accumulate(a)))

for i, j in enumerate(1,itertools.accumulate(a)):
    print(i,j)
```

Explaination: lambda x:1/x creates on-fly function that would transform n to 1/n. map maps that function to the range of value starting from 1 to 1000. I then pass this to accumulating 1/1+1/2..... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that python2 will return 0 for 1/x and your sum will lead to 1 at the end. For getting float output(i.e. 0.25 for 1/4) one of the numbers have to be converted to float(either 1 or either x). Hence, the right way would be

```
sum = 0
for x in range(1, 1001):
    sum += (float(1)/x)
    print(sum, x)
```

Comment: Or you can import division from the future. from \_\_future\_\_ import division. The Python 2 division would be replaced by 3 and business as usual :)